# Volley Request spawns Threads

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am using volley to access my REST service. This is how my code looks like:

```
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Method.POST, "http://....",
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            ...
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            ...
       }
    }
) {
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
    ...
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    ...
}};

postRequest.setShouldCache(false);
Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(postRequest);
```

Everything works as expected, but when i open ADV i can see, that five new threads are created which have status "Wait" from the beginning. These threads also never get deleted.

So my question is: is this normal behaviour?  is it any problem for the performance of my app? Cause i got the impression that it slows down after a while. I end up having several hundred Threads with status "Wait" in the list until i really close the App and start it again.

Answer (score 0):

According to [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/idea133/src/com/android/volley/RequestQueue.java), yes, it's a normal behavior, because it's create a pull of threads right after your create new request queue.

Comment: Thank you, so would using a singleton help? https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton

Comment: It has nothing to do with singleton. Volley creates 5 thread in pool just in order to do parallel request more in more efficient way. You shouldn't worry about that.